# "export 'Enable Persistent Token' was not found in '@angular/fire/firestore'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angularfire

I am developing an Ionic5 / angular app. I am using angularFire2 to store images in FireBase. Everything worls perfect when doing ionic serve.

The problem is that, I am trying to deploy it, and when running ionic build --prod, the following error appear.

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ngfactory.js 39:4422-4448
> "export 'EnablePersistenceToken' (imported as 'i15') was not found in '@angular/fire/firestore'
> at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
> at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\webpack\lib\dependencies\HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
> at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1425:22)
> at C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1221:10
> at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :40:1)
> at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
> at Compilation.finish (C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1216:28)
> at C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:662:17
> at _done (eval at create (C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :7:1)
> at eval (eval at create (C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :70:22)
> at C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1148:12
> at C:\Users\c.falv\Proyectos Ionic\TP\HigieneYSeguridad\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1060:9
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)

Answer (score 1):

This was a problem related to to library angularFire2. It seems that, despite the name, you are supposed to used AngularFire, wich is the newest version. Regards